# Time complexity - comparing different algorithms

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o, complexity-theory

I am trying to understand computational complexity and how fast a computer can execute instructions depending on the algorithm being used. I found a tutorial on http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/15-200/lectures/aa/ where it shows different complexity classes and the time it takes to run each depending on how many items it is running.

For example, if a computer can compute 1 instruction every 10^-9 seconds, how do you get those running times. I've been trying to understand the table because it doesn't go too deep into the calculations.

For instance, O(1) - why is it 10^-7 seconds - shouldn't it just be 10^-9?
Also for the other run times i'm not sure how you get those values.

Comment: O(1) does not mean "1 instruction", it means "constant time". Big-O notation gives you a way to evaluate how the growth of the input impacts the running time, it does not give you a formula for calculating running time from input size (directly).

Comment: Say you are looking for a specific house, a house address is a constant time lookup (the address exactly communicates its location), directions to a house (without its address) is liner time (the amount of time it takes increases with the number of steps in your direction). A vague description requiring you to to look at every house and compare it to every other house before you are sure you found it is exponential growth (the amount of time is equal to the square of the houses you must search through)

Answer (score 0):

When you say 10^-9, it will mean that there is only one instruction for the given program. Usually its not.

Moreover, the table is giving some approximate information for comparison.

Another information which is given in initial paragraph is the actual program under evaluation to actually calculate the number of instructions executed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it would be less confusing if the table had assumed that O(1) operation is exactly 1 operation. However, above the table it is saying "Then the following table gives us an intuitive idea of how running times for algorithms in different complexity classes changes with problem size." So the focus of the entries is on the ***change*** in running time as N grows.

So, I could explain the data on the table as follows. It assumes that in each complexity class if it takes a certain amount of time for N = 10 then how much it will **change** if N becomes 100, 1000, ... .

For example, in case of O(1), if you assume that it takes 10^-7 for N=10, it will take the same  amount for larger N's because the complexity is independent from N.

Another row that might be confusing is O(N^3): you can say if it takes 10^-5 for N=10 then for N=100 this value is multiplied by 10^3, and so on. In fact for N=10 it does not exactly calculate 10^3 x 10^-9, but rather assumes some running time and ***only focuses on change*** in the running time when N becomes larger.